# Is there any differences between using text-davinci-003 with the Azure API vs. with the OpenAI API?

Tags: nlp, language-model, azure-ml, gpt, api

I wonder whether there are any differences between using text-davinci-003 with the Azure API vs. with the OpenAI API.

Comment: Can you flesh out your question with some background? Do you think there would/should be? Or you are seeing differences and wondering if you have a bug?

Comment: @DarrenCook "Do you think there would/should be" No idea, I use OpenAI and wonder if it's worth trying Azure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also asking myself the same question to figure out whether it's worth migrating for increased availability or is Azure simply wrapping the original API. This is the only info I was able to find on the matter:

> Azure OpenAI Service gives customers advanced language AI with OpenAI
> GPT-3, Codex, and DALL-E models with the security and enterprise
> promise of Azure. Azure OpenAI co-develops the APIs with OpenAI,
> ensuring compatibility and a smooth transition from one to the other.
>
> With Azure OpenAI, customers get the security capabilities of
> Microsoft Azure while running the same models as OpenAI. Azure OpenAI
> offers private networking, regional availability, and responsible AI
> content filtering.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/overview#comparing-azure-openai-and-openai